# How can I use a "Cloudinary like" service to upload images by url?

Tags: product-images, image-upload

We are trying to learn the best way to upload our images both individually and in bulk- and to figure out the selections for displaying images.

Does anyone use a service like Cloudinary for images?
Are you using the Magento product interface, a spreadsheet or some other way to upload your images?

I thought it worked last week but this week it is not accepting the url at all.

Answer (score 1):

There is now a free, official Magento Cloudinary Plugin on the Magento Connect Store which automates the migration of Magento Images into Cloudinary.

It also provides the common settings that ecommerce users look for from the plugin.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/cloudinary-image-management-in-the-cloud.html

Answer (score 0):

With Cloudinary you can indeed upload images from any remote URL. You can have a look at the following for more information:
http://cloudinary.com/documentation/fetch_remote_images

Comment: I was just trying to copy the image cloudinary url to our products in the "Images"  or import images via import by spreadsheet. Nothing was working.  
It ended up being some other issue unrelated to cloudinary. 
Do I remove the questions?